# React-Hook-Form. Diffrent validation on diffrent events

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have just started using React Hook Form and I can't figure out how to implement different validation for different events.

So, i have an input

```
 <input
        type="text"
        {...register("name", {
          required: 'is required',
          maxLength: {
            value: 40,
            message: 'max length is 40',
          },
          pattern: {
            value: /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*$/,
            message: 'wrong format',
          }         
        })}
      />
```

I want the "required" rule to trigger **only** on the "onSubmit" event and not on any other event. And all other rules, no matter what I specify, should trigger on the "onBlur" event.

I specified the onBlur mode in the useFome options for this.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    watch,
  } = useForm<IFields>({
    mode: 'onBlur',
  });
```

But in this case, if I focus on the input and then remove it, the required rule will still work.

I tried this options.

```
    formState: { isSubmitting }
```

```
 required: isSubmitting ? 'is required' : false,
```

But the options isSubmitted and isSubmitting are triggered only after validation.

Comment: Consider a different way of thinking about your problem: you always want to apply all rules (a required field is always required, unless you have conditional logic of course, but I'm assuming you don't), but you want to be selective about what error messages you want to show given a certain formState (submitted vs not submitted). For this reason, I'd probably use `Controller`